# Kill Jenkins Slave when the build process is done?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using ec2 plugin in Jenkins to bring up slaves . I have configured in such a way that the Slaves will die if they are idle for 30 min.
Due to various reasons I want the Slaves to be killed as soon as the build process is completed .

Is there a way to do this ? If so can it be done through pipeline script.